# Does "brew install --cask emacs" install a GUI version of Emacs for M1?

Tags: mac

Just wondering if "brew install --cask emacs" installs Emacs for the M1 with the GUI.

Answer (score 2):

[According to the formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/c5ae3285a70367cd322e56caa61112bed675065f/Casks/emacs.rb), the cask grabs the app from emacsformacosx.com. And [their ‘about’ page says](https://emacsformacosx.com/about) that ARM binaries are included starting with version 27.2-1, which is below the current version in the cask.

(I didn't verify the installation myself, however, due to not having an M1 Mac.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It does. After installing the `.dmg` you may have to correct some of the symlinks yourself. (I did when I installed this past Fall, and I don't know if that's been addressed.)

```
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS
❯ v
drwxrwxrwx@ 21          - nega  5 Nov  2021 ./
drwxrwxrwx@  7          - nega 27 Mar  2021 ../
.rwxrwxrwx@  1      3,408 nega 27 Mar  2021 Emacs*
.rwxrwxrwx@  1  7,170,624 nega 27 Mar  2021 Emacs-arm64-11_2*
.rwxrwxrwx@  1 15,488,160 nega 27 Mar  2021 Emacs-arm64-11_2.pdmp*
.rwxrwxrwx@  1  9,209,536 nega 27 Mar  2021 Emacs-x86_64-10_11*
.rwxrwxrwx@  1 15,483,720 nega 27 Mar  2021 Emacs-x86_64-10_11.pdmp*
.rwxrwxrwx@  1  7,337,760 nega 27 Mar  2021 Emacs-x86_64-10_14*
.rwxrwxrwx@  1 15,483,960 nega 27 Mar  2021 Emacs-x86_64-10_14.pdmp*
.rwxrwxrwx@  1 15,483,720 nega 27 Mar  2021 Emacs.pdmp*
lrwxr-xr-x   1         14 nega  5 Nov  2021 bin -> bin-arm64-11_2/
drwxrwxrwx@  6          - nega 27 Mar  2021 bin-arm64-11_2/
drwxrwxrwx@  6          - nega  5 Nov  2021 bin-x86_64-10_11/
drwxrwxrwx@  6          - nega 27 Mar  2021 bin-x86_64-10_14/
drwxrwxrwx@  8          - nega 27 Mar  2021 lib-arm64-11_2/
drwxrwxrwx@  9          - nega 27 Mar  2021 lib-x86_64-10_11/
drwxrwxrwx@  8          - nega 27 Mar  2021 lib-x86_64-10_14/
lrwxr-xr-x   1         18 nega  5 Nov  2021 libexec -> libexec-arm64-11_2/
drwxrwxrwx@  5          - nega 27 Mar  2021 libexec-arm64-11_2/
drwxrwxrwx@  5          - nega 27 Mar  2021 libexec-x86_64-10_11/
drwxrwxrwx@  5          - nega 27 Mar  2021 libexec-x86_64-10_14/
```